# How to save my high scores to a text file unity

Tags: c#

I have created a streamreader and streamwriter to load and create the file. But im having trouble iterating through the list of the top five high scores to update the high scores when a new one is achieved.

```
     public int highscore;
    public static int score;
    //public new string name;
    private string initials;
    public List<int> highscores;
    //public List<Person> highscores;
    Text HighScoreText;

    void Awake()
    {
        HighScoreText = GetComponent<Text>();
        score = 0;
        highscores = new List<int>();
        score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score",0);
       highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0); ;
        LoadScore();
        UpdateScore();

    }
    void UpdateScore()
    {


        HighScoreText.text = "HighScore:" + score;
//Here I get an error cannot apply indexing with type int
        if (score > highscores[4].s)
        {
            highscores.Add(score);
            highscores.Sort();

            highscore = score;
            HighScoreText.text = highscore.ToString(); ;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You meant `if (score > highscores[4]) {`? This `.s` at the end makes no sense. And if you add a new highscore, don't forget to drop the sixth/lowest!

Answer (score 0):

You declared `highscores` as a `list` of `int`: `public List<int> highscores;`

Then you are checking `if (score > highscores[4].s) { ... }` what is the `.s` for? You don't need it at all. Just check `if (score > highscores[4])` and your code shall compile normally.

Also, after compiling, you would want to check your logic by debugging your code statement by statement. Using F-10 `step-over` option if you are using Visual Studio.